# Android Marshmallow Runtime permissions-not working

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

I was working on Android-M runtime permissions. I wanted to add a Location permission to one of my fragments. Here is my code. Android asks for permission, but even if I deny the permission, nothing happens, it dismisses the dialog box, but still the `activateGPS()` works and returns value. Thanks in advance.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        // Marshmallow+
        getPermissionToReadUserContacts();
    } else {
        // Pre-Marshmallow
        System.out.println("CODMOB: Device not marshmallow");
        activateGPS();
    }


    activateGPS();

    return view;
}
private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 1;
public void getPermissionToReadUserContacts() {
    System.out.println("CODMOB: getPermissionToReadUserContacts()");
    // 1) Use the support library version ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(...) to avoid
    // checking the build version since Context.checkSelfPermission(...) is only available
    // in Marshmallow
    // 2) Always check for permission (even if permission has already been granted)
    // since the user can revoke permissions at any time through Settings

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // The permission is NOT already granted.
            // Check if the user has been asked about this permission already and denied
            // it. If so, we want to give more explanation about why the permission is needed.
            System.out.println("CODMOB: The permission is NOT already granted.");
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                // Show our own UI to explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
                // before actually requesting the permission and showing the default UI
                System.out.println("CODMOB: We need to access location.");
            }else{

            // Fire off an async request to actually get the permission
            // This will show the standard permission request dialog UI
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);

            }
        }
    }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    // Make sure it's our original READ_CONTACTS request
    if (requestCode == LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST) {
        if (grantResults.length>0 &&
                grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            System.out.println("CODMOB:permission granted");
            activateGPS();
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Read Contacts permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            System.out.println("CODMOB: permission denied");
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Read Contacts permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code to

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        // Marshmallow+
        getPermissionToReadUserContacts();
    } else {
        // Pre-Marshmallow
        System.out.println("CODMOB: Device not marshmallow");
        activateGPS();
    }
    return view;
}
```

in-spite of fragment....add this method in your activity too

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.containerView);
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry for that. That was an error from my part. but still I have found that the code is not reaching inside of onRequestPermissionResult(). Else ,When I deny the permission,I should have got a message "CODMOB: permission denied" in the logcat.

Comment: have you added onRequestPermissionResult() in your container activity

Comment: and the second time i open the app, the permission dialog does not even shows up. ie.,requestPermission method is not being executed i think.

Comment: for 'and the second time i open the app'...are you selecting never ask checkbox

Comment: No..You mean I should add the ' onRequestPermissionResult() ' in my fragments parent class instead of writing it inside the fragment class?

Comment: No..never selected 'never as again'

Comment: see my edit...add method in both fragment and activity with slight difference

Comment: sorry if I'm asking too much..I'm new to developemnt..whats this containerView?

Comment: means your activity from which you launch your fragment...you are trying this code in fragment...right?

Comment: Yeah..I mean,in code snippet, whats this? 'findFragmentById(R.id.containerView)'

Comment: R.id.containerView means id of your framelayout in your activity...inside which you load your fragment

Comment: Yea got it.. one more question..after the permission is denied ,execution automatially points to getPermissionToReadUserContacts()..why is it so/

Comment: cant understand your scenario...pz elaborate

Comment: Once I denied the permission, Its seen that ,the code again started execution from the getPermissionToReadUserContacts().

Comment: When I give 'never as again' option, the activity that contains this fragment gets reloaded again and again,just like in an infinite loop. :/

Comment: its not possible actually...please post your whole fragment..code

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        final String[] permission = new String[]{
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                android.Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        };
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission, 0);
    }
```

use above code in your activity it may help.